# How and where do I start to 'create' the second card?

Tags: flashcards, cards

Warning:
I am only just getting started with this LaTeX and have no experience in writing this 'code-like' language.

I started on making cards for a boardgame for my pupils. 
After finally getting 1 card, both question and answer fixed, and the layout being quite ok I am stuck. 
I have no idea how or where (what command what line etc) to start or create a new card and responding answer.

Kind regards,

Code Sample

```
\documentclass[a7paper,print,10pt,grid=rear]{kartei}
%Voor info googelen op 'LaTeX kartei'
%a7paper: bepaalt hoe groot de fiches worden.  a6-a7-a8-a9 zijn de opties
%grid: geeft aan of er snijlijnen moeten geprint worden.  
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{icomma}

%\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}%enkel nodig om chemische formules te kunnen gebruiken


%Om te zorgen dat het antwoord in het midden van de kaart komt te staan.  
\newcommand{\antwoord}[1]{
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
#1
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
}

\newcommand{\vraag}[1]{#1}

\newcommand{\kaart}[2]{
\begin{karte}[Vraag]{\vraag{#1} }
\answer{Antwoord}

\antwoord{#2}

\end{karte}
}

\author{T. Dierckx}

\begin{document}

\kaart{Bereken:

$2^{5}\cdot 2^{2}=$}{$2^{7}=128$}

\end{document}}
```

Comment: Hi, if this helps you in anyway...  http://www.math.utah.edu/~jasonu/flash-cards/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. It will be easier for others to help if you include the actual code of your document instead of a screenshot (you can edit your question and use the "code sample {}" button to format selected lines as code). That having been said, it looks like your `\kaart` command takes two arguments, and you may have only given it one argument on line 39.

Comment: @MikeRenfro  Like this? (the code sample) 
I did (i think) include the second part of the \kaart command but it wasn't shown in the printscreen. My apologies.

Comment: for each card, you need to create following command: `\kaart{<question>}{<answer>}` and replace `<question>` and `<answer>` accordingly.

Comment: And  i can write it just right after what line?

Comment: As @ebo just commented, you can copy and paste your existing `\kaart` command, changing the items in the two outermost pairs of braces to your desired questions and answers. On your current card, the first pair of outermost braces starts with `Bereken:` and ends with `=$` and the second pair starts with `$2^` and ends with `128$`.

Comment: Also, [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner)

Comment: I added codesample:{\kaart{Los de vergelijking op:

x+15 = -x+5}{ x+15 = -x+5 

2x=-10

x=-5}}

Right before the 'end document' line and it works!! Thanks so much for your answers Mike, Ebo and Crypto!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a new card, just insert following command in your document (i.e. between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`) and replace `<question>` and `<answer>` accordingly: **`\kaart{<question>}{<answer>}`**
You need to call this command for each card you want to create.

Here is an example with a second card (see below for detailed explanations):

```
\documentclass[a7paper,print,10pt,grid=rear]{kartei}
    %Voor info googelen op 'LaTeX kartei'
    %a7paper: bepaalt hoe groot de fiches worden.  a6-a7-a8-a9 zijn de opties
    %grid: geeft aan of er snijlijnen moeten geprint worden.  
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[dutch]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{icomma}

    %Om te zorgen dat het antwoord in het midden van de kaart komt te staan.  
    \newcommand{\antwoord}[1]{
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \begin{center}
            #1
        \end{center}
        \vspace*{\fill}
    }

    \newcommand{\vraag}[1]{
        #1
    }

    \newcommand{\kaart}[2]{
        \begin{karte}[Vraag]
            \vraag{#1}
            \answer{Antwoord}
            \antwoord{#2}
        \end{karte}
    }

    \author{T. Dierckx}

\begin{document}
    \kaart{Bereken: $2^{5}\cdot 2^{2}=$}{$2^{7}=128$}
    \kaart{Bereken: $e^{i\pi}+1=\text{?}$}{$0$}
\end{document}
```

---

## How does your code work?

- First, you define what kind of document/layout you want creating, with some options. `LaTeX` will thus know which already-implemented rules have to be followed.

  ```
  \documentclass[a7paper,print,10pt,grid=rear]{kartei}
  ```
- Then, you load some so-called packages: they are literally packages that gives you the ability to use new rules (i.e. macro-commands) and that can set up some `LaTeX`-settings for you.

  ```
  \usepackage[<eventually some options>]{<package-name>}
  ```
- Then, you define your own commands

  ```
  \newcommand{\<name-of-the-new-command}[<number-of-arguments]{<definition of what the command does>}
  ```
- And eventually, given all these settings and informations, you begin to describe what is the content of your document.

  ```
  \begin{document}
      <content-of-your-document>
  \end{document}
  ```

## How does the `\kaart` command work?

You have define in your preamble (all the code from `\documentclass` to `\begin{document}`) a command called `\kaart`. Let see how it works.

- `\newcommand{\kaart}`: you create a new command named `\kaart`! It will return an error if a command already has this name.
- `[2]`: this command has two arguments. Thus, when you want to use this command, you have to write `\kaart{<first-argument>}{<second-argument>}`.
- `{ <command-definition> }`: what the command does is defined within these curly-brackets.

  - `\begin{karte}[Vraag]`: it begins a (previously define in `kartei.cls` file) environment named `kaarte` with the argument `Vraag`. This environment will be closed with `\end{karte}`.
    -`\vraag{#1}`: You then call the command `\vraag` with one argument `{ <argument>}`. `#1` means that this argument is actually the `<first-argument>` you gave as argument of `\kaart`.
  - `\answer{Antwoord}`: You call the command `\answer` with the argument `Antwoorkd`.
  - `\antwoord{#2}`: You should have guessed it: you call the command (or function, or macro) `\antwoord` with one argument, which is `<second-argument>`, the second argument you gave when you called the `\kaart` command.

So writing `\kaart{<first-argument>}{<second-argument>}` is the same than writing

```
\begin{karte}[Vraag]
    \vraag{<first-argument>}
    \answer{Antwoord}
    \antwoord{<second-argument>}
\end{karte}
```

But it's shorter... and you can easily re-use it!

Thus, within your document (i.e. between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`) you can call several times the command `\kaart{<question>}{<answer>}` as in the example.